# Fundamental group of a torus with two points connected by a segment

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $C = \{(x, y, z)\in \mathbb{R}^3  : (x − 2)^2 + y^2 = 1, \, z = 0\}$, $X = \{(x, y, z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : y = z = 0, x \in [−1, 1]\}$ and $T$ be the torus obtained by rotating $C$ around $y$ axis. Calculate the fundamental group of $Y=X \cup T$.

I've tried using the Seifert–Van Kampen theorem, taking the open and path connected subspaces such that $Y=U_1 \cup U_2$ as $Y = U_1-\text{the equatorial circumference of the torus}$  and $U_2=T\setminus \{(0,0,0)\}$. By appling some deformation retracts I've found out that $\pi_1(U_1)\simeq \mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$, $\pi_1(U_2)\simeq \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi_1(U_1\cap U_2)\simeq \mathbb{Z}$, where $\pi_1(A)$ denotes the fundamental group of $A$. Now I can't figure out what is $\pi_1(Y)$; in particular, using group presentations and relations, I can't understand what are the relations "induced" by the elements of $U_1\cap U_2$ in the presentation of $\pi_1(Y)$. Hopefully everything makes sense. Thanks everybody.

Comment: Hint: your space is homotopy equivalent to the wedge product (one-point union) of a circle $S^1$ and $T$.

Comment: @Rob Arthan I've been thinking about it but I'm not exactly sure how to justify it. It may sound trivial but is moving the two end points still an homotopic equivalence? Because I can understand "continuous shrinking and warping", but is it there a more rigorous way to show it?  (Mind you, my algebraic topology's knowledge is pretty basic).

Comment: I confess that giving the full details is quite tedious. You have to figure out the maps from $f : Y \to nS^1 \wedge T$ and $g : S^1 \wedge T \to Y$ that form the homotopy equivalence first. for the first one consider the map $\Bbb{R}^2\to \Bbb{R}^2$ given in polar coordinates by $(r, \theta) \mapsto (\max(0, r-1), \theta)$ - it collapses the unit disc to a point. Using this map you can collapse a subspace of $Y$ that is contained in $T$ and contains the endpoints of $X$ to a point. That gives you $f$. In the other direction, get $g$ by laying the half of $S^1$ that contains the base point ...

Comment: over the line $X$. Now you have to show that $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$ are homotopy equivalent to the identity functions on $S^1 \wedge T$ and $Y$ respectively. That isn't too hard to see.

Comment: A better idea might be to use Seifert-van Kampen after noting that $Y$ is homeomorphic to $(S^1 \sqcup T)/\sim$ where $\sim$ identifies half of $S^1$ with a line on $T$ joining the endpoints of $X$. So $Y \simeq  S^1 \cup T$, with $S^1 \cap T$ contractible.